# ActiveRecord not using counter_cache?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have two simple models:

```
class Push < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :opened_pushes
end

class OpenedPush < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :push, :counter_cache => true
end
```

However, if I do

```
a_push.opened_pushes.count
```

It queries the db, rather than using `opened_push_count` column present in Push. I thought it was smart enought to do that...is this how it's suppose to be?

Comment: It does not seem, from [the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/de1b687239832f336b9453493701955ab4d6d6a2/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/belongs_to.rb#L23), that the `AR::Base::count` method would be affected. I'm guessing you probably already know that and are probably calling `.count` on something else?

Answer (score 0):

Needed to call `size`, as opposed to `length` or `count` which will generate a query.